# Apache Shiro how to authenticate REST service

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, shiro

I want to create REST service which can be used on many clients. For security authenticaton I want to use Apache Shiro with OAuth to secure the REST service. How I can implement this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have implemented Shiro with Database as credentials storage. But for this I need additional information.